# JQuery Accordion and Google Maps - not an issue with map centering/displaying

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxb7P.jpg

Linked above are three tabs made with JQuery UI Accordion. The third (which is opened in the picture) contains an embedded Google Map. The empty red rectangle is the location where the map should appear. The above error is only present in Safari, I couldn't replicate it in any other browser.

The map is wrapped inside a div called *map canvas*

```
<h3 id="pasek3"><a href="#"></a></h3> // third tab
<div id="content_wrap">
<div id="podPaskiem3"> // under the panel
<p id="lewo1"> // left half
CONTACT/ADRESS DETAILS
</p>
<p id="prawo2"> // right half
<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
</p>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<!--content_wrap--></div >
```

These are that divs properties

```
mapCanvas {
border:  0;
width:  500px;
height:  350px;
margin:  0 auto;
}
```

Here is the script responsible for displaying and centering the map once the third tab is opened:

```
<script>
var map = null;  
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.2729782, 20.9861867);
function initializeMap() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    return new google.maps.Map($('#mapCanvas')[0], myOptions);
}
    // Function for adding a marker to the page.
    function addMarker(location) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
    }
    // Testing the addMarker function
    function TestMarker() {
            CentralPark = new google.maps.LatLng(52.2729782, 20.9861867);
            addMarker(CentralPark);
    }
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();

    $("#accordion").bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.newContent.attr('id') == 'content_wrap' && !map)
        {
            map = initializeMap();
                 TestMarker();
        }
    });
});
  </script>
```

Comment: Post the solution as an answer and then accept it. This is common practice on StackOverflow if person asking the question has already found the solution. Otherwise the question will appear as unanswered and it will not be helpful for people having similar problems in the future. Also include the code of the solution within your answer, so it can be reachable in case the original solution disappears from the Internet.

Comment: There are 8 sentences in your post, but none of them mentions that the link does not solve your problem. Actually there is even something opposite: "_here is what worked for me..._". Could you please rephrase your question maybe and mention why there is this link within your question? It really looks like you describe some problem, then point the solution and say "that worked for me". Make yourself extremely clear - this is probably the reason, why you did not get any answer yet.

Comment: In case you have stumbled upon this thread looking for a solution to an issue with Google Map displaying/centering, here is what worked for me [link](http://www.essentialwebconcepts.com/blog/2011/03/22/fixing-google-maps-rendering-problem-in-jquery-accordion/). This is not the solution to the problem detailed in the question - this is a solution to with Google Maps not displaying the map as such properly in an accordion. @Tadeck, ok, perhaps you were right.